# getting name of next post in tumblr

Tags: navigation, tumblr

I'm making a custom tumblr theme. I'm displaying one post per page. How can I get the title of the next page.

For example, when using pagination:

```
  {block:Pagination}
  {block:NextPage} <a href="{NextPage}" class="nav">Next &#187;</a>  {/block:NextPage}
  {/block:Pagination}
```

This will create a link as such Next » whereas I want the link to be as such [name of next post »](http://foobar.com)

Anybody have any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to use the Tumblr API. You can check it our at [http://www.tumblr.com/api] - be warned though, you'll need some knowledge of jQuery or javascript [1](http://www.tumblr.com/api)

Comment: Sad this isn't just an innate part of Tumblr